# Preserving list structure with sorting a list of sublists in Lisp

Tags: sorting, common-lisp

So I have list structure as follows:

```
(defparameter *list* '(   ((2 2 2) (0.1))
                          ((5 5 5) (0.4))
                          ((1 1 1) (1.2))
                          ((3 3 3) (3.4))
                          ((4 4 4) (4.5)) )
```

I want to sort it where it returns an output of

```
'( ((1 1 1) (1.2))
   ((2 2 2) (0.1))
   ((3 3 3) (3.4))
   ((4 4 4) (4.5)) )
```

So here is my attempt:

```
(sort *list* 
      #'(lambda (a b)
          (< (squared a '(0 0 0))
             (squared b '(0 0 0)))) 
      :key #'first)
```

Where squared takes in two lists and calculates the squared distance of each element and sums them (ie (squared '(1 2 3) '(0 3 5)) => 48))

I am sorting the list of lists by its first element of the sublist '(# # #) and calculating the distance from '(0 0 0) then sorting by that distance.

But my attempt outputs the following => `((1) (1 1 1) (2) (3) (2 2 2) (4) (5) (3 3 3) (4 4 4) (5 5 5))`

How do I sort by '(# # #) but also preserve the list structure? Also using Common Lisp!

Thank you!

EDIT

I had typed into lisp wrong but correctly into this forum.  I had typed list as the following

(defparameter *list* '(   (2 2 2) (0.1)
                            (5 5 5) (0.4)
                            (1 1 1) (1.2)
                            (3 3 3) (3.4)
                            (4 4 4) (4.5) ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Careful: `sort` may destroy the input data.  Your input as shown here contains literal data.  Modifying literal data has undefined consequences.  Use `copy-tree` or `copy-list` to create non-literal from literal data.

Answer (score 1):

Actually my first attempt works! I just typed in *list* incorrectly (forgot some parenthesis).  So it sorts and maintains the structure!